# SpriteKit action does not run when it's made from an eclipse

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a few nodes I need to rotate around in a circle, I have the code set up as perfectly as far as I know yet the action does not run, when I change the path.addEcplipse line to path.addCurve the node runs the action perfectly, here is a [video](https://youtu.be/abnouhOhm8g)

The path's code:

```swift
    func createEyePaths() {

        eyePath1.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        eyePath2.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))


        eyePath1.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(gameScene.frame.height / 1.5), height: CGFloat(gameScene.frame.height / 1.5)))

        eyePath2.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(gameScene.frame.height / 2), height: CGFloat(gameScene.frame.height / 2)))

        eye1Action = SKAction.follow(eyePath1, asOffset: true, orientToPath: true, duration: 2)

        eye2Action = SKAction.follow(eyePath2, asOffset: true, orientToPath: true, duration: 4)

        viewLine.path = eyePath1
        gameScene.addChild(viewLine)

        for n in 0...3 {
            eyes[n]!.run(eye1Action)
        }
        for n in 4...7 {
            eyes[n]!.run(eye2Action)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why this didn't work but using a UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect()) as the initialiser and UIBezierPath.cgPath as the argument for the action seemed to do the trick